# Django + execute asynchronous process?

Tags: django, multithreading, asynchronous, queue, task

I am implementing a feature in a new project and I was wondering what was the optimal solution to it. The feature itself consists of sub functionality as follows: starting a process, stop a process, and checking if the process is running...all these done in a non-blocking way with django. I am trying to avoid stuff like RabbitMQ, etc. I was thinking maybe of using threading or cron.

EDIT: these functionality need to be triggered from a view.

Any comments or suggestions are the most welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can surely use [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) with [the database backend](https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/master/celery/backends/database.py) instead of RabbitMQ. Personally, for simple tasks I tend to just write a [custom mangement command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-management-commands/) launched from cron, that gets its input from some database table (i.e. Django model) which is populated by Django view(s).